# "unexpected" error while executing bat file

Tags: batch-file

I am getting this error

```
Z:\Utilities>Test.bat
    -10314679.html: was unexpected at this time.
Z:\Utilities>
```

while executing this bat file

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=1 delims=@" %%A in (_HashList-1.tmp) do (
    call set myParam="%%A"
    call :myParseLine %%myParam%%
)
exit /b

:myParseLine
    call set myParam=%~1
    call set myPartLine=%myParam:~0,8%
    if "%myPartLine%" == "MD5 hash" ( 
        call set myPartLine=%myParam:~12%
        exit /b 
    )
exit /b
```

The file _HashList-1.tmp contains

```
MD5 hash of z:\Church\Messages\Emails\19981112-The Stranger- You got to read this.... (fwd)-10314679.html:
966b538d0f52fc66bbb7ef4fd98ec1ca
CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.
```

Any clue what I am doing wrong?

If I comment out the line

```
call set myPartLine=%myParam:~12%
```

then it works. I need to refer to "myParam" there to do further processing.

I am writing a bat file that generates checksum for all the files in a drive and stores the same for later reference.

Comment: You need to properly explain what you're trying to do. Your question states, `I am writing a bat file that generates checksum for all the files in a drive and stores the same for later reference`, but there is nothing whatsoever in that script which generates hashfiles. All your script looks like it is trying to do is read each line of `_HashList-1.tmp` up to the first instance of `@`, _which doesn't exist on any line_, then sets `!myPartLine!` to the rest of the line after `MD5 hash of `.

Comment: Why are you constantly using CALL SET. There is no need for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is occurring in this block of code

```
if "%myPartLine%" == "MD5 hash" ( 
    call set myPartLine=%myParam:~12%
    exit /b 
)
```

The error occurs when the value of variable myParam is:

```
MD5 hash of z:\Church\Messages\Emails\19981112-The Stranger- You got to read this.... (fwd)-10314679.html:
```

This line:

```
    call set myPartLine=%myParam:~12%
```

expands to

```
    call set myPartLine=z:\Church\Messages\Emails\19981112-The Stranger- You got to read this.... (fwd)-10314679.html:
```

The `)` in `(fwd)` is closing your IF block prematurely, and the parser sees `-10314679.html:` as an error.

You could prevent that error by enclosing your assignment within parentheses as follows:

```
    call set "myPartLine=%myParam:~12%"
```

The `)` would be quoted, so it won't close the parenthesized block

But your code is a hot mess that really should be completely refactored (rewritten). It is obvious you have picked up snippets of batch coding techniques without understanding what they do, or how and when to apply them. For example:

- Enabling delayed expansion without ever using it
- Using CALL unnecessarily/inappropriately

I've got ideas how to more cleanly implement your existing code logic. But I'm not convinced your logic is actually what you want, so I am reluctant to take a stab at cleaning up your code.

Comment: I agree the script is not as anyone would like. I am learning while I am coding. Now I am having this problem when the line contains "&". What should I use? Here is the line : "z:\Church\Messages\Emails\20061013-God_s perfect will-Q &-266668.html";14-05-2015;05:51:34 PM

Comment: @SandeepSD - There is so much wrong with your code - I think Stack Overflow is not the best venue for your task at this point. I believe you are going to need a lot of back and forth help, and this is not a good forum for that. Might I suggest the DosTips forum - https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=3

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example of one method which should work on all files in the current directory outputting the results to a text file, `hashes.txt`.

From the Command Prompt:

```bat
For %A In (*) Do @For /F "Delims=" %B In ('CertUtil -hashfile "%A" MD5 2^>Nul^|Find /V ":"') Do @(Echo=%A: %B)>>"hashes.txt"
```

From a batch file:

```bat
@For %%A In (*) Do @For /F "Delims=" %%B In ('CertUtil -hashfile "%%A" MD5 2^>Nul^|Find /V ":"') Do @(Echo=%%A: %%B)>>"hashes.txt"
```

*I'll leave you to read `For /?` in order to modify the first `For` loop to recursively process all files in a directory/drive*